# Get Payload of ICMP Connection (C++)

Tags: c++

I want extract payload from ICMP pakage, here a code from internet in linux (I'm on windows) but not work.

```
/*..........*/
char * data_re;
char buf[1024];
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

int nbytes = recvfrom(sock,buf,sizeof(buf)-1,0,(struct sockaddr *)&dest,&af);
if (nbytes < 0)
        {return 0;}

if(nbytes > 0){
            struct iphdr *ip;
            icmph = NULL;
            ip = (struct iphdr *) buf;
            if (nbytes > sizeof(ip)) {
                nbytes -= sizeof(ip);
                icmph = (struct icmphdr *) ip + 1;
                if (nbytes > sizeof(icmphdr)) {
                    nbytes -= sizeof(icmphdr);
                    data_re = (char *) (icmph + 1);
                    data_re[nbytes] = '\0';
                    printf("%s", data_re);
                    //fflush(stdout);
                }
            }
        }
/*..........*/
```

Comment: Since `ip` is a pointer, you should use `sizeof(*ip)` to get the size of the `iphdr` struct rather than `sizeof(ip)`.

Comment: Thanks but not work.

Comment: How are you setting up your socket to do this?